# MacBook Pro USB-C adapter and regular USB devices compatibility

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt

I got a new MacBook Pro from late 2016, MacOS Sierra, 2 thunderbolt 3 ports.

In this machine I need to plug in one external monitor via HDMI, and a few USB devices (mouse and keyboards). For this I bought an adapter that plugs in to the Mac's USB-C port, and supplies two USB 3.1 ports, one HDMI port and a power delivery for the USB-C power supply. The adapter is: Promate uniHub-C (https://www.promate.net/products/unihub-c)

The power supply works, when I plug in the power cable to the adapter, the computer charges.

The HDMI works with another monitor.

My external USB hard drive works, so the mouse/keyboard issue feels strange.

When I have a USB keyboard plugged in, and an external hard drive - the System Report > USB shows as follows. The keyboard and the hard drive are both plugged in to the uniHub-C.

In the finder I see the hard drive though, seems to work well.

*Screenshot showing the System report*
[image: System report]

*Screenshot showing that the finder can find the connected hard drive*
[image: My Passport is found]

Here is the problem: the USB slots doesn't seem to do much. When I plug in mouse and keyboard in the adapter, nothing happens. I was worried that perhaps I need another kind of USB-C => USB 3 adapter for regular USB devices to work, but I can't confirm that.

How can I verify I have an active connection in each USB slot?

Comment: What does System Report show under USB when using the adapter? - In generel, no further adapter should be necessary for connecting a USB mouse/keyboard.

Comment: I added this info in the edit now, I'm not sure if this is expected output.

Comment: How is the hard drive connected? - Via the uniHub-C? The output you have from System Report does not show the hard drive, so it seems you haven't copied the output correctly?

Comment: The uniHub is connected to the laptop's thunderbolt-3 socket, the hard drive and the keyboard are connected to the uniHub. The uniHub is also connected to the wall socket for power, and to a monitor via HDMI. I updated the question with some screenshots.

Comment: Is your external HDD a USB3, or USB2 device?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the manufacturer?  It sounds like a defect in the USB hub.

Comment: Allan, I have not - but I will definitely contact them now.

Comment: Ali Chen, the drive is compatible with either USB2 or 3.

Comment: Just to be clear, a USB3 device is called "USB3 device". This includes backwards compatibility with USB2 as it has a nearly SEPARATE USB2 interface. But in USB3 devices the USB3 interface has a priority. A USB2 device doesn't have USB3 wires. Therefore it is incorrect to say "either USB2 or 3", it is not "either". However, you can force any USB3 device into USB2 mode by using a USB2-only cable - the u-B USB2 plug is compatible with u-B USB3 connector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this particular product (uniHub-C) has its own idea about compliance to USB specifications. The designers seem to cut off the USB 2.0 part of the VIA hub design. First sign is that their marketing blurb doesn't mention support for legacy (HS, FS, LS) devices, which is strange - in marketing, more is merrier. Second, the web page shows some goofy "USB Super-fast" logo, which in no way corresponds to the official USB-IF certification logo,

[image]

I suspect you fall for a wrong device.

Comment: This is concerning indeed. My hard drive is probably USB3, it's a MyPassport. So you think that USB2 protocols doesn't work with the uniHub but since the hard drive is USB3, that's the reason that one shows up?

Comment: @miphe, why don't you try any known good USB 2.0 pen drive in your hub? I am sure you have several on them in your drawer...

Comment: I have confirmed that this is the case. I purchased a USB-C => USB 2.0 HUB/Adapter (http://tinyurl.com/y79emk4j) and the components that didn't work with the Promate HUB does indeed work with this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with this hub:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07FX2LW35/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FX2LW35)

Peripheral connection doesn't work (power, display and network do), and seems to be known issue (search for peripheral or Logitech) in the comments.

I connected another USB C hub in the other port in my Macbook and it indeed works.

Dongle hell.

Edit: from the comments in the link above and elsewhere I have read, some of these USB C Hubs have a problem with input devices connected at the same time (power + something else) from the same Thunderbolt port in the Macbook.

I have reached out to the manufacturer to see where the fault might lie, and if there is a mitigation. For now, using another hub without power/display in the other Thunderbolt port works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Would you perhaps edit this to explain how it addresses the main idea - how to tell if a port and device work. We generally remove "me too" answers, but this question wasn't super clear so I don't want to remove your answer until it's clear or documented what the known issue is.